# File Upload from FLEX or ActionScript 3 to ASPX .NET?

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I would like to know how to upload a file from ActionScript 3 (From a FLEX Application) to a Dot Net Back End, maybe to an ASHX file, an ASPX file or similar and using C# as core backend language.

Thanks!!

Comment: I found an example here but not sure if it works:
http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/flex-file-upload-with-aspnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FileREference](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class to pass the file from Flash Player to the backend service.  Googling provides a bunch of examples on how to do this, here are the top 2:

http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/flex-file-upload-with-aspnet/

http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2008/03/29/upload-multiple-files-using-asp-net-amp-adobe-flex.aspx

Comment: The first link you placed it's the one that worked for me as you can see on my own comment above but thanks anyway dude... it's the correct answer!!

Comment: Glad to help!  Thanks for the upvote even if you beat me to the answer. ;)